# How to Coordinate Multiple Uses of \footnotemark and \footnotetext in a Tikzpicture Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

Consider

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=blue!25,text width=0.94\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{13}{18}\selectfont \textbf{First sentence.\footnotemark \, Second sentence.\footnotemark \, Third sentence.\footnotemark}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\footnotetext{first footnote}
\footnotetext{second footnote}
\footnotetext{third footnote}
\end{document}
```

which produces the tikzpicture

[image]

with the footnotes

[image]

QUESTION: How may I correct the above code so that the correct footnote marks (1 followed by 2 followed by 3) appear in vertical sequence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the numbers of the footnotes explicitly like this:

```
\footnotetext[1]{first footnote}
\footnotetext[2]{second footnote}
\footnotetext[3]{third footnote}
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice, simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional argument of `\footnotetext`, and count "backwards" (rather than hard coding `1` and `2`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=blue!25,text width=0.94\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{13}{18}\selectfont \textbf{First sentence.\footnotemark \, Second sentence.\footnotemark \, Third sentence.\footnotemark}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\footnotetext[\numexpr\value{footnote}-2]{first footnote}
\footnotetext[\numexpr\value{footnote}-1]{second footnote}
\footnotetext{third footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]